# Convert a Pandas DataFrame into a multiple rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with "N" rows and 4 columns (N,4).I want to make something like this (1, 4.N). I would like (4,4) to become a row every time

For example if I have:

```
A  B  C  D 
1, 5, 9, 13 
2, 6, 10, 14 
3, 7, 11, 15 
4, 8, 12, 16 
1, 11, 56, 9 
1, 34, 87, 91
67, 67, 9, 1 
1, 37, 77, 9
```

I want  a result  like this:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3 C3 D3 A4 B4 C4 D4
1  5  9  13 2  6 10  14 3  7  11 15 4  8  12  16
1 11 56  9  1  34 87 91 67 67  9 1  1  37 77  9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `reshape` from `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(
        """ 
1, 5, 9, 13  
2, 6, 10, 14  
3, 7, 11, 15  
4, 8, 12, 16  
1, 11, 56, 9  
1, 34, 87, 91 
67, 67, 9, 1  
1, 37, 77, 9 """
    )
)

pd.DataFrame(
    df.values.reshape(2, 16),
    columns=[f"{i}{n}" for n in range(1, 5) for i in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]],
)
```

This will return:

```
   A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2  A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4  D4
0   1   5   9  13   2   6  10  14   3   7  11  15   4   8  12  16
1   1  11  56   9   1  34  87  91  67  67   9   1   1  37  77   9
```

as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ignoring_gravity. Now I have Valueerror:                
 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 28 into shape (2,16)

Comment: What dataframe are you using? The one you posted in your question is not of size 28

Comment: So,I have already read my csv file as DataFrame. it contains 1600 rows ans now i want it like (100,16).Suppose I already have my Dataframe

Comment: Suppose I already have my Dataframe. that mean I don't need thist line: df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: .I tried it but nothing. Thanks for your help. I tried another way

Comment: I find the solution, thank you very much @ ignoring_gravity

Comment: Can you share your solution in a separate answer?